# How to use drop = F correctly in R to preserve matrix structure when subsetting

Tags: r, subset

I want to preserve the matrix (or array) structure after subsetting, and it was my understanding that this was achieved with the parameter `drop = F`. However, this does not seem to be the case:

```
> m = matrix(1:8, 4)             # Toy example
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4    8
> is.matrix(m[1:2,])             # Subsetting first 2 rows yields a matrix
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(m[1,])               # Subsetting just one row yields a vector
[1] FALSE
> is.matrix(m[1,,drop=F])        # drop=F does not help!
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: For me, it is returning TRUE i.e. `is.matrix(m[1,,drop=F])
#[1] TRUE`

Comment: @akrun This is crazy, isn't it? :-)

Comment: This is in R 3.4.2 on windows

Comment: $version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)"

Comment: It could be that you have an object `F` defined earlier i.e. `F <- 1;
 is.matrix(m[1,,drop=F]) ;
[1] FALSE`  It is always good to specify FALSE/TRUE instead of F/T i.e. `is.matrix(m[1,,drop=FALSE])#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Checked on R 3.1.3 and it is returning TRUE.  So, I am guessing the problem with the object assignment

Comment: @Toni Try `is.matrix(m[1,,drop=FALSE])`

Comment: @jogo `> is.matrix(m[1,,drop=FALSE]) [1] TRUE` What is going on?

Comment: @Toni After removing the object `F` (which you didn't have shown to us) `rm(F)` you will get your expected result also with `is.matrix(m[1,,drop=F])`.

Comment: @jogo It works! `> m = matrix(1:8, 4) > is.matrix(m[1,,drop=F])
[1] TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?logical`

> TRUE and FALSE are reserved words denoting logical constants in the R
>   language, whereas T and F are global variables whose initial values
>   set to these. All four are logical(1) vectors.

So, as we mentioned in the comments, if we create an object with 'F' earlier and then use `drop=F`, this will result in the specific problem

```
F <- 1
is.matrix(m[1,,drop=F]) 
#[1] FALSE
```

It is always better to use `TRUE/FALSE` instead of substring `T/F` for this particular problem because we cannot assign the reserved words as object name i.e.

```
TRUE <- 5
```

> Error in TRUE <- 5 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

```
FALSE <- 1
```

> Error in FALSE <- 1 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

```
is.matrix(m[1,,drop=FALSE]) 
#[1] TRUE
```